# Import SQL Server data into Excel with user-defined data types

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, sqldatatypes

I have a SQL Server and I want to import data from a view into Excel via Microsoft Query.

Sounds easy right? Well it isn't as some of the columns are of a user-defined data type.

**tblSeller**:

- ID: `int`
- Name: `nvarchar(50)`
- Country: `CountryName:nvarchar(50)`

**tblBuyer**:

- ID: `int`
- Name: `nvarchar(50)`
- Country: `CountryName:nvarchar(50)`

**tblSale**:

- ID: `int`
- SellerId: `int`
- BuyerId: `int`

**vSales**:

```
SellerName, SellerCountry, BuyerName, BuyerCountry
```

(I think you get the idea that I have joined `tblSale` with `tblSeller` and `tblBuyer` and want to get names and countries - and since this is just an example I have left out all other stuff which would make it a useful view!!!)

The view `vSales` works like a charm on my server: It shows me all my information. The problem occurs when I want to import it into Excel 2010 via "From Microsoft Query" (Data => From Other Sources => From Microsoft Query). All columns with a user-defined data type are not available!

Only if I import data directly via "From SQL Server" (Data => From Other Sources => From SQL Server) I get my data. But as my real view contains hundreds of columns and nearly 200.000 rows that is not and option as I need to specify which columns I want to import.

So to put it short: how to import data from a SQL Server view into Excel using a Microsoft Query in order to be able to limit number of columns?

Comment: Changing to non-user-defined data types is not an option :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for misinforming you... I tried to simplify my question - which also removed the problem!

The definition of the countries was: st_CountryName:nvarchar(50).

And it seems as if Excel is not able to import types where the underscore is a part of the "name". Sorry for misleading you all in my question - but hope someone else will find this answer helpful!